# jQuery find() element by data attribute, which value is object

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find element with `jQuery` by its data attribute value. The problem is, that the value is object and `find()` function doesn't work properly for me...
Data attribute value looks like this:

```
<tr class="odd" data-row="{"id_construction":2,"created_date":2015-11-30}">
```

And here is my script:

```
for(var i = 0; i < dataList.length; ++i){
    var constructionId = dataList[i].id_construction;
    if (constructionId == selectedConstructionId) {
        $('.gridator').find('tr[data-row={id_construction:}').addClass('selected-construction');
    }
}
```

value of `dataList[i]` is `{"id_construction":2,"created_date":2015-11-30}`

How should I edit this script to find the wanted element? (Element which `data-row` value is equal to `dataList[i]` value)

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/og1j1wc3/4/

Comment: it's completely unclear what do mean by `find the wanted element`?

Comment: @Curiousdev Element which `data-row` value is equal to `dataList[i]` value

Comment: First of all do `data-row='{"id_construction":2,"created_date":2015-11-30}'` on your `tr` since your data-row would return only a `{`

Comment: try `$('.gridator').find('tr[data-row='+dataList[i]+']')` since tr has the attribute you are selecting

Comment: @guradio it threw me this log: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: tr[data-row=[object Object]]`

Comment: pass as string use `JSON.stringify(dataList[i])`

Comment: @guradio could you please help me more with that? because I've never used this, don't know how to use `stringify`, if I have to put this into the variable?

Comment: try this way `$('.gridator').find('tr[data-row='+JSON.stringify(dataList[i])+']')` @HS1993

Comment: @guradio Thank you! But I got this log: `SyntaxError: illegal character`

Comment: @guradio It will only work if JSON is stored in specific format, which is an incorrect assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery attribute selectors work with strings, not with objects stored as JSON.
You will have to iterate through every attribute value in order to find a necessary object:

```js
var $greens = $("div").filter(function() {
  return $(this).data("p").isGreen === true;
});

console.log($greens.length); // 3
$greens.css("color", "green");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-p='{"isGreen": true}'>
  one
</div>
<div data-p='{"isGreen":true    }'>
  two
</div>
<div data-p='{"isGreen": false}'>
  three
</div>
<div data-p='{ "otherAttribute": 42, "isGreen": true }'>
  four
</div>
```

As you can see in this snippet, whitespaces and other attributes do not affect how this works because your work with it as with data, not as a string.

Note that according to documentation jQuery **[`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** returns an object if data attribute contains JSON object:

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null).
>   When the data attribute is an object (starts with '{') or array (starts with '[') then jQuery.parseJSON is used to parse the string; it must follow valid JSON syntax including quoted property names. If the value isn't parseable as a JavaScript value, it is left as a string.

Comment: It works here great, but when I tried to use it, got this log: `TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined[Learn More]`

Comment: @HS1993 If it works here, then may be you do something wrong :) Show how use use and reproduce this problem at JSFiddle.

Comment: @HS1993 As you can see, JSFiddle highlights your HTML with red color, because your HTML syntax is incorrect. You have a quote inside attribute which closes an attribute. It is simply invalid.

Comment: But it's generated in PHP:
`echo '<tr class="' . (($i%2) ? 'odd' : 'even') . '" data-row=\'' . htmlspecialchars($_control->prepareJsonRowData((array)$row)) . '\'>';`
where I tried to replace quotes (as you can see) but still the same error..

Comment: @HS1993 I do not know PHP and can't help with it :) I can tell you how to solve this JS problem and it works. You can validate the HTML from this fiddle using any HTML validator and will get errors.

Comment: So I tried to edit Fiddle, but still doesn't work, take a look please: https://jsfiddle.net/og1j1wc3/7/

Comment: @HS1993 Your JSON is still invalid. JSON cannot store date in the given format. You need to store it as a string: https://jsfiddle.net/og1j1wc3/8/